# Python list index out of range on return value of split

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a simple script that is trying to extract the first element from the second column of a .txt input file.

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    f = open(sys.argv[1], "r");
    print "file opened";

line = [];

for line in f:
    line = line.strip("\n ' '")
    line = line.split(",") 
    print line[1]

f.close();
```

My input file looks like this:

```
Client 192.168.1.13 said ``ACC: d0bb38f18da536aff7b455264eba2f1e35dd976f,389182.567,-0.042,-0.893,0.333''
Client 192.168.1.13 said ``ACC: d0bb38f18da536aff7b455264eba2f1e35dd976f,389182.590,-0.036,-0.905,0.273''
Client 192.168.1.13 said ``ACC: d0bb38f18da536aff7b455264eba2f1e35dd976f,389182.611,-0.046,-0.948,0.204''
Client 192.168.1.13 said ``ACC: d0bb38f18da536aff7b455264eba2f1e35dd976f,389182.631,-0.074,-0.978,0.170''
Client 192.168.1.13 said ``ACC: d0bb38f18da536aff7b455264eba2f1e35dd976f,389182.654,-0.100,-1.006,0.171''
```

I want my delimiter to be a comma. When I print the length of the line out, I'm getting 5 elements (as expected). However, whenever I try to index the list to extract the data (i.e., when I call `print line[1]`), I keep getting the following error:

```
file opened
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stats.py", line 13, in <module>
    print line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why it's out of range when clearly it isn't.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback, and the values of any relevant variables: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I'm a total newbie in python. How do I provide you with the full traceback?

Comment: `print line` and see what you get

Answer (score 9):

I would guess you have a blank line somewhere in your file. If it runs through the data and then generates the exception the blank line will be at the end of your file.

Please insert

```
print len(line), line
```

before your

```
print line[1]
```

as a check to verify if this is the case.

You can always use this construct to test for blank lines and only process/print *non*-blank lines:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
       # process/print line further
```

Comment: @ayl If this or any of the other answers on this page solved your problem, please consider [*accepting this question*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. It'll will reward both parties with some rep points and mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with list and trying to get value at particular index, it is always safe to see in index is in the range

```
if len(list_of_elements) > index: 
   print list_of_elements[index]
```

See:

```
>>> list_of_elements = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> len(list_of_elements)
4
>>> list_of_elements[1]
2
>>> list_of_elements[4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Now you have to find out why your list did not contain as many elements as you expected

Solution:

```
import sys

if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
    print "file opened"

for line in f:
    line = line.strip().strip('\n')
    # Ensure that you are not working on empty line
    if line:
        data = line.split(",") 
    # Ensure that index is not out of range
    if len(data) > 1: print data[1]

f.close()
```

Comment: I found some of my input files had parts of the data cut off on the last line of the text file (<fewer than 5 elements in a column). That was causing the index error. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @ayl: I just wanted to show approach and safeguards that should always be used when using list index.

Answer (score 2):

you probably have empty line(s) after your data, I ran your test code without them it worked as expected.

```
$ python t.py t.txt
file opened
389182.567
389182.590
389182.611
389182.631
389182.654
```

if you don't want to remove them, then simply check for empty lines.

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip(): # strip will remove all leading and trailing whitespace such as '\n' or ' ' by default    
        line = line.strip("\n ' '")
        line = line.split(",") 
        print line[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to catch the exception an print the offending lines

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip("\n ' '")
    line = line.split(",") 
    try:
        print line[1]
    except IndexError, e:
        print e
        print "line =", line
        raise   # if you don't wish to continue
```